# What blue and/or black options exist for moving +1/+1 counters?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I am making a [Szadek, Lord of Secrets](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Szadek%2C%20Lord%20of%20Secrets) deck, and I am looking for cards that can move +1/+1 (or similar) counters from one of my creatures to him. For instance, if I have a bunch of +1/+1 counters on [Brineborn Cutthroat](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brineborn%20Cutthroat), I would want to move the counters over to Szadek. I know of [Fate Transfer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fate%20Transfer); are there any other cards that do the same thing in blue and/or black mana?

Comment: @PhilipKendall the question must be about moving counters. I don't see how the other interpretation makes sense given what the cards do.

Comment: I couldn't find anything that exists, but OP might be looking for an ability like "If you would put one or more counters on a creature, you may put those counters on another target creature instead." The closest thing I found is [The Ozolith](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=+[the+ozolith]).

Comment: I've made an executive decision and made this question unambiguously about moving counters which already exist. Ethan - if you meant something else by "redirect abilities", please edit your question to explain precisely what you meant because "moving counters" is not and has never been redirecting an ability.

Comment: Not within the scope of the question, but [this scryfall query](https://scryfall.com/search?q=f%3Acommander+id%3Aub+o%3A%2Fput+.%2B+%5C%2B1%5C%2F%5C%2B1+counters%3F+on%2F+-o%3A%2Fcounters%3F+on+%28%7E%7Cit%29%2F&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name) finds UB cards that put counters on arbitrary creatures.

Answer (score 1):

The always wonderful [Scryfall](https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=-oracle%3Aremove+%28oracle%3Amove+oracle%3Acounter%29+color%3C%3DUB+legal%3Acommander) reveals a number of possibilities; of these your best option is almost certainly [The Ozolith](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=The%20Ozolith) which will pick up any counters from creatures which leave the battlefield and then at start of combat you can then move those counters onto any creature.

Other than that, things that can move counters from arbitrary creatures:

- [Leech Bonder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Leech%20Bonder) can move one counter at a cost of {2}{Q}.
- The land [Nesting Ground](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nesting%20Ground) can move one counter at a cost of {1}{T}.
- [Simic Fluxmage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Simic%20Fluxmage) can move one +1/+1 counter at a cost of {1}{U}{T} (and comes with Evolve so can generate its own +1/+1 counters)

[Steel Dromedary](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Steel%20Dromedary) and [Weapon Rack](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Weapon%20Rack) come into play with a small supply of +1/+1 counters and can move those counters onto arbitrary creatures.

The other option you may want to consider is some way to make Szadek an artifact creature (e.g. [Liquimetal Coating](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Liquimetal%20Coating), many other options exist) and then use Modular creatures to get +1/+1 counters onto Szadek.

But the long and short of it is that there aren't many good options - which isn't surprising, +1/+1 counters are primary in green and white.